# Multi hop proxy with pycharm (or filezilla)

Tags: ftp, sftp, socks5

### Environment

I have

- My Local Machine A (mac)
- remote bastion B (ubuntu)
- remote server C (ubuntu)
- remote SFTP server D (ubuntu)

A --> B --> C --> D

I want to connect to D from A with sftp client (any client is okay except it's expensive)

- I have pycharm, intelij. (pro)
- I have filezilla (free)

I have ssh configuration to connect C

```
Host bastion_b
  Hostname bastion.yogiyo.co.kr
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/mykey.pem
  ForwardAgent yes
  User me
  Port 22

Host server_c
  Hostname server_c
  User me
  Port 7722
  ProxyCommand ssh -W %h:%p bastion_b
```

### Question

- is there any way to connect D with any sftp client?

### What I have tried

- I can not connect to C with pycharm ssh (because I'm using ssh jump)
- I tried `ssh -D <ip of server D>:<port of server D> server_c`. and I tried to connect it with pycharm sftp, but it didn't work.

Comment: I do not know pycharm – but does your question imply that pycham uses OpenSSH internally? In OpenSSH, the easiest way to tunnel connection is using `ProxyJump` directive: `ProxyJump hop1,hop2,...`